# Linux: Padding text to fixed length

Tags: linux, text, command-line

My text looks like this:

```
some text..............................12
some more text......................65
even sometext...................................68
```

In other worlds, it's a TOC. I'd like the lines to be of equal length, say 32 bytes, padded w/ `.`. How do I do this in Linux? So far I've done everything w/ sed, but I'm not sure about this one

EDIT: I should've probably added that a solution involving any tool / language available on Linux command line is fine

Comment: Maybe [this link](https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/132905-printing-fixed-width-columns.html) can help?

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` program will do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env awk -f

BEGIN {
    FS = "\\."
    width = 32 # total desired width
    pad = sprintf("%*s", width, "") # " " * width
    gsub(" ", ".", pad) # "." * width
}

{
    padwidth = width - length($1) - length($NF)
    printf("%s%.*s%s\n", $1, padwidth, pad, $NF)
}
```

Put it in a text file, run `chmod +x` on that file to make it executable, then run something like this:

```
./my_awk_script my_input_file
```

The result for your example input is:

```
some text.....................12
some more text................65
even sometext.................68
```

Note: `NF` is the Number of Fields, so `$NF` is the last token on a line.